# How to put all this links in one text document

Tags: python, list, selenium, hyperlink, document

So, here is the deal: I have this code bellow and it produces multiples results, how do i put all this results in a single document? I was wondering if it was possible to make all of this a list of links. It's comming this way

```
['http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171101-45305-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171004-45277-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Minist%C3%A9rio', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171004-45277-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Minist%C3%A9rio', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171109-45313-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171219-45353-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171122-45326-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171122-45326-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171229-45363-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171229-45363-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180105-45370-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/minist%C3%A9rio']

['http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180202-45398-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180202-45398-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180131-45396-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20100702-42626-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20101202-42779-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Minist%C3%A9rio', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20101220-42797-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Minist%C3%A9rio', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20100904-42690-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20101102-42749-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20100514-42577-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro', 'http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20100915-42701-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/Minist%C3%A9rio']
```

But i wanted something like a list, like this:

```html
http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171101-45305-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro
http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180202-45398-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro
http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20180131-45396-spo-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro
http://acervo.estadao.com.br/pagina/#!/20171101-45305-nac-1-pri-a1-not/busca/ministro
```

A bunch of links in the order they were get in a .txt document. I have no idea how to start (i'm a newbie in programming).

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
x = 1

driver.get("http://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro%3B minist%C3%A9rio|||/Acervo/capa//1/2000|2010|2010///Primeira")
time.sleep(5)
page_number = driver.find_element_by_class_name("page-ultima-qtd").text

for i in range(int(page_number)):
    link = ("http://acervo.estadao.com.br/procura/#!/ministro%3B minist%C3%A9rio|||/Acervo/capa//{}/2000|2010|2010///Primeira").format(x)
    #driver.get(link)
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "LEIA ESTA EDIÇÃO")))
    references = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("seta-right").click()
    time.sleep(1)

    print(references)        
    x = x + 1
    #print(x)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution: format your `references` list before printing, ie

```
# print(references)
print("\n".join(references))
```

or print them one by one (might be a bit longer but well):

```
# print(references)
for ref in references:
    print(ref)
```

and then use your OS redirections to redirect the output to a file (linux example):

```
$ python yourscript.py > myurls.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['a','b','c']

#if your output your getting is lists you could put them all into one list first

master = list1 + list2
#concatenated lists
print(master)

#then simply send to file

with open("filenames.csv", 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for row in master:
        wr.writerow([row])
```